# How to use \tikzmark with pLaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark, ptex

Usually I use the standard `latex` from MiKTeX when i use TikZ, which works good. 
But now I need to use `platex` from `w32tex` instead to include Japanese characters, which gives me the error:

```
Package pgf Warning: Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvips.def does not support marking the current position.
```

with a reference to the first line I use `\tikzmark`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You might have a look to [our start page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436): it will help you to familiarize with the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that you are (probably) out of luck. Marking position requires pdfTeX primitives (or derivatives thereof), and pTeX doesn't have them.

Answer (score 2):

Actually modern pTeX (e-pTeX) implements `\pdfsavepos` and you can use marking in TikZ/pgf.
TikZ/pgf raises the error because it does not know that this feature exist in pTeX.
You can solve this problem by using [the `pxpgfmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pxpgfmark).

Here is the method using `dvipdfmx` as a DVI driver:

1. Add `dvipdfmx` to the global option (option of `\documentclass`).
2. Add `\usepackage{pxpgfmark}` after TikZ or pgf.
3. Compile with `platex`, which is alias to `eplatex`.
4. Convert the DVI file with `dvipdfmx`.